# Como iniciar no CakePHP3.x

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3

Estou começando agr com o **cakephp**, segui o tutorial do bookmarker, mas existe algum material com uma didática simples, explicando os conceitos, que são usados no cake?
vejo youtuber usando o **AuthComponent**, mas não dizem o que é pra que serve, quais os principais métodos/funções/actions, qual a diferença do **find** pro **get**, o que é a **Entity** e a **Table** presentes na pasta Model e etc... ou só lendo e relendo a documentação oficial mesmo?
Até porque se usa muitos jargões, e pra quem tá iniciando fica mais difícil ainda.

Desde já, grato!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O melhor material mesmo é o manual do CakePHP. Esse material é bem completo e muito alto explicativo
Algo que complica é que quando você vai mais fundo no Framework muito dessa documentação esta disponível apenas em inglês.

Aconselho a inicialmente usar os tutorias do [cookbook](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/index.html)

AuthComponent - É um componente do cakephp para gerenciamento de sessões e permissões do usuário, fornecendo funções para login, controle de acesso por perfil de usuário.Conytrola identificação e autorização.

find pro get, o que é a Entity e a Table

Entity e table são os componentes do model
Na table você define métodos e propriedades para o modelo de tabela, validação de dados e de criação de objetos.
Na entity você modela como a entidade da tabela será em si tratada 
por exemplo podemos definir na entity quais propriedades do objeto serão enviadosa view, são possíveis de ser editados e quais não

get e find depende da definição da classe
mas aqui entendi que se refere aos métodos fornecidos Pela ORM do cake para busca em banco.
 O get faz a busca unicamente por ID. ou seja sempre retorna um objeto especifico da do modelo.
O find permite a implementação de um método de pesquisa, podendo fazer busca por outras propriedades do objeto que não o id.

Espero ter ajudado